# C# MVC, Generic Repository and Unit Testing with Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have to test a method which returns true or false if date range overlaps with any item of list.

**List items are holiday requests:**

```
public class HolidayRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set;  }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; } 

}

public interface IHolidayRequestRepository :IGenericRepository<HolidayRequest>
{ 
    bool IsHolidayRequestAlreadyCreated(String EmployeeId, DateTime DateFrom, DateTime DateTo); 
} 

public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity Get(object id);
    //skipped 
}
```

Now unit tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private Mock<IHolidayRequestRepository > _holidayRepository;
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _holidayRepository = new Mock<IHolidayRequestRepository >();
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        //Arange
        IList<HolidayRequest> list = new List<HolidayRequest>
        {
             new HolidayRequest{ Id =1, EmployeeId="E00001", DateFrom = new DateTime(2019,09,13,0,0,0), DateTo = new DateTime(2019,09,13,0,0,0)}
        };
        _holidayRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(list.AsQueryable);

        var howMany = _holidayRepository.Object.GetAll().Count();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, howMany); //<- Test passed

        bool val = _holidayRepository.Object
             .IsHolidayRequestAlreadyCreated("E00001", new DateTime(2019, 9, 12), new DateTime(2019, 9, 14));

        ////Assert
       Assert.IsTrue(val);  //<- Test error - always return false

    }
}
```

I expect the test result to be true, but it always return false even if method is simplified to return always true

Method:

```
     bool IsHolidayRequestAlreadyCreated(String EmployeeId, DateTime DateFrom, DateTime DateTo);
```

was simplified to always return true:

```
public class HolidayRequestRepository : GenericRepository<HolidayRequest>, IHolidayRequestRepository
{
    public HolidayRequestRepository(MvcDbContext context) : base(context) {  }

    public bool IsHolidayRequestAlreadyCreated(string EmployeeId, DateTime DateFrom, DateTime DateTo)
    {
        return true; 
    } 

}
```

How should I mock this method to use the logic from HolidayRequestRepository  class?

Comment: You are not mocking `IsHolidayRequestAlreadyCreated` method thus mock returns default value, which is `false` for `bool`. Just setup mock for `IsHolidayRequestAlreadyCreated` method.

Comment: You mock **dependencies** of your system under test, not the system itself. Otherwise all you'll be testing is whether the mock does what you instructed it to. And since you've not instructed your loose mock to return something when calling `IsHolidayRequestAlreadyCreated()` on it, it returns its default, in this case `false`. Remove this mock altogether for this test.

Comment: There is little value in testing a mock of your implementation. Try creating a real instance and calling the method. In your example the `MvcDbContext` may be something you'd want to mock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you do not test the real implementation of the code but the mocked code. In a unit test, you typically want to test the real implementation. So in your case, you'd have to create an instance of `HolidayRequestRepository` and call the method on this object, e.g.

```
var hrr = new HolidayRequestRepository(...);
var actual = hrr.IsHolidayRequestAlreadyCreated(empId, dtFrom, dtTo);
Assert.True(actual);
```

In order for this to work, you need to setup the DbContext that is provided to the constructor so that the data that are required for a test case are available.

Comment: Thank You :),I stubbornly tried to use the interface